# How do I change the position of the tooltip when using Dojo's dijit DropDownButton?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Current markup looks like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DropDownButton" data-dojo-props="dropDownPosition: 'above'">
    <span>413</span>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.TooltipDialog">
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">413</button>
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">617</button>
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">860</button>
      <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button">203</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything worked fine until I added the `data-dojo-props` attribute. With the attribute in place, the widget won't render the dialog at all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where did you find the 'dropDownPosition' property?  I've never seen that one.

Comment: Their [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.7/dijit/form/DropDownButton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you quote indicate that `dropDownPosition` takes an array, not a single string.  Change `data-dojo-props="dropDownPosition: 'above'"` to `data-dojo-props="dropDownPosition: ['above']`"

e.g.
http://jsfiddle.net/RoystonS/E4RHv/

Comment: Well...would you look at that. Thank you.